# Hello world, why this code doesn't work?

Tags: php, if-statement, exit

Why doesn't my browser show me any text ?
Why doesn't it exit ?
Why exit doesn't work?

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST)){
    exit;
}else{
    echo "any text";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors? The text "enter code here" would not parse.

Comment: I think this question does not deserve downvotes. The author is a novice, but he tries something and he does not understand, that's why he asks. Even if it is a simple question for most of us, it is not for him. It's difficult to google the solution or find error.

Comment: @Voitcus It's not hard to read documentation at all.

Comment: @PLB I know, but if you're learning you don't know that "enter code here" is something wrong. You might don't even know that there is something like `error_reporting()`, that you have it off. You don't see any errors, so you don't know there is a syntax one.

Comment: @Voitcus I bet `enter code here` appeared from SO text editor. The actual failure in OP's question was that (s)he was checking if `$_POST` was set or not and since `$_POST` is superglobal it's always set (unless configuration is modified) and this is clearly written in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have any POST data, your variable $_POST is still an empty array, so this means that it is set. 
If you want to do exit, you should check $_POST variable with [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

Please go at PHP manuals and check [PHP Basic Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php)

Remove the line

> enter code here

replace

```
if(!isset($_POST)){ exit; }
```

with

```
if(empty($_POST)){ exit("There is no Post data"); }
```

and it should work..

Normally the $_POST is always set!

So you can check if its empty or no - if you need to know if there is POST data..

Answer (score 1):

You should be check for count($_POST) == 0 . Because isset will always be true as this variable is available.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the text "enter code here" and try.
2. add error_reporting(1); at the top of the page and try.
3. Check the value in `$_POST`, `print_r($_POST);`

   ```
    <?php 

      error_reporting(1);

      print_r($_POST);

      if(empty($_POST)){ exit; }
      else { echo "any text"; }

    ?>
   ```

Comment: This "enter code here" line interprets later.

Comment: You have mistype here: `error_reportin(1);`

Comment: `isset($_POST)` doesn't make any sense.